# Uploading an image from ReactJS to AWS S3 Using Lambda Function + API Gateway

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am new to ReactJS and AWS. I wanted to create a simple ReactJS frontend with a simple button to upload an image to S3 via API gateway integrated with a Lambda function (The lambda function creates the presigned url for file upload). I am running into CORS errors, I have tried everything I found online, nothing seems to work. The main thing I want to achieve is uploading an image to S3 and getting the url of the image to post it into a DynamoDB table as a reference. I am not sure how to make all these components to work together. I followed this article: https://blog.webiny.com/upload-files-to-aws-s3-using-pre-signed-post-data-and-a-lambda-function-7a9fb06d56c1

Here is my Lambda Code:

```
const S3 = require("aws-sdk/clients/s3");
const uniqid = require("uniqid");
const mime = require("mime");

/**
 * Use AWS SDK to create pre-signed POST data.
 * We also put a file size limit (100B - 10MB).
 * @param key
 * @param contentType
 * @returns {Promise<object>}
 */
const createPresignedPost = ({ key, contentType }) => {
const s3 = new S3();
const params = {
  Expires: 60,
  Bucket: "uploadimage",
  Conditions: [["content-length-range", 100, 3000000]], // 100Byte - 3MB
  Fields: {
    "Content-Type": contentType,
    key
  }
};

return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
s3.createPresignedPost(params, (err, data) => {
  if (err) {
    reject(err);
    return;
  }
  resolve(data);
});
});
};

/**
 * We need to respond with adequate CORS headers.
 * @type {{"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": string, "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": boolean}}
 */
const headers = {
 "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
 "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true
};

module.exports.getPresignedPostData = async ({ body }) => {
  try {
    const { name } = JSON.parse(body);
    const presignedPostData = await createPresignedPost({
      key: `${uniqid()}_${name}`,
      contentType: mime.getType(name)
    });

return {
  statusCode: 200,
  headers,
  body: JSON.stringify({
    error: false,
    data: presignedPostData,
    message: null
  })
};
} catch (e) {
 return {
   statusCode: 500,
   headers,
   body: JSON.stringify({
     error: true,
     data: null,
     message: e.message
   })
 };
}
};
```

I have created AWS API with lambda proxy integration feature enabled, to ensure the headers are passed from here that avoid CORS errors, somehow it still shows them.

My ReactJS frontend component code looks like this (Taken from the tutorial linked above):

```
import React from "react";
import Files from "react-butterfiles";

function Upload() {
  /**
   * Retrieve pre-signed POST data from a dedicated API endpoint.
   * @param selectedFile
   * @returns {Promise<any>}
   */
  const getPresignedPostData = (selectedFile) => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

      // Set the proper URL here.
      const url = "https://xyz---.amazonaws.com/Upload/";

      xhr.open("POST", url, true);
      xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
      xhr.send(
        JSON.stringify({
          name: selectedFile.name,
          type: selectedFile.type,
        })
      );
      xhr.onload = function () {
        resolve(JSON.parse(this.responseText));
      };
    });
  };

  /**
   * Upload file to S3 with previously received pre-signed POST data.
   * @param presignedPostData
   * @param file
   * @returns {Promise<any>}
   */
  const uploadFileToS3 = (presignedPostData, file) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const formData = new FormData();
      Object.keys(presignedPostData.fields).forEach((key) => {
        formData.append(key, presignedPostData.fields[key]);
      });

      // Actual file has to be appended last.
      formData.append("file", file);

      const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open("POST", presignedPostData.url, true);
      xhr.send(formData);
      xhr.onload = function () {
        this.status === 204 ? resolve() : reject(this.responseText);
      };
    });
  };

  /**
   * Component renders a simple "Select file..." button which opens a file browser.
   * Once a valid file has been selected, the upload process will start.
   * @returns {*}
   * @constructor
   */
  return (
    <Files
      onSuccess={async ([selectedFile]) => {
        // Step 1 - get pre-signed POST data.
        const { data: presignedPostData } = await getPresignedPostData(
          selectedFile
        );

        // Step 2 - upload the file to S3.
        try {
          const { file } = selectedFile.src;
          await uploadFileToS3(presignedPostData, file);
          console.log("File was successfully uploaded!");
        } catch (e) {
          console.log("An error occurred!", e.message);
        }
      }}
    >
      {({ browseFiles }) => (
        <button onClick={browseFiles}>Select file...</button>
      )}
    </Files>
  );
}

export default Upload;
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated! Ultimately, I want to upload an image to s3 and then store image url in dynamodb table as a reference. Thanks!

Comment: Have you configured CORS on the bucket as in the tutorial? Have you enabled CORS on the API Gateway resource as well?

Comment: Yes, I have done all that! My s3 bucket cors configuration is as follows: 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>